Nuxt 2 Viem TypeError: Cannot convert a BigInt value to a number at Math.pow
I have a project with Nuxt 2, and I want to support WalletConnect v2. For this reason, I added the WalletConnect dependencies, but it doesn't compile. I added WalletConnect and related dependencies to the transpile section, and after that, the build was successful. However, when I run the project, I get the following error on the client:

TypeError: Cannot convert a BigInt value to a number at Math.pow

This error is related to the viem library. Even when I use another library like @web3-onboard, I encounter the same issue because of dependencies.

Not really a specific package issue as foundable on any search engine. BigInt should be natively available in your browser nowadays: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt#browser_compatibility

I'm using the latest version of Chrome. I also added Browserslist to the package.json. Maybe the issue occurs because I added it to the transpile section

What happens if you do not transpile it, what's the error?

I got many typescript error during build like:
in ./node_modules/viem/_esm/errors/rpc.js
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (9:48)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type ...
|             cause,
|             docsPath,

        metaMessages: metaMessages || cause?.metaMessages,


|         });
|         Object.defineProperty(this, "name", {

This is not really a TS error, more of a build setup. Feel free to post the error fully by editing your question and also sharing the related config file.
